# imagecreatefromjpeg php not outputing

Tags: php, jpeg

I am trying to regenerate a image via imagecreatefromjpeg, rename it and also store in another location on the server, but nothing is getting outputed. Here is what i have:

```
$src = 'http://example.com/assets/stock/myimagetoregenerate.jpg';

$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);

imagejpeg($dest,'stock/test.jpg', 100);
```

When going to this directory, no image has been generated.

I also try and output the image rather than save it, by adding this to the above code:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
```

But the img src is just the current page url.

All permissions have been set to read and write, so that isnt the issue.

GD 2.1.0 is enabled on the server.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to *open* and then *reencode* the image in the first place; it'll just lose more of its quality. Just *download* the file with `curl` or such.

Comment: I would just use the php `copy` function, as it works on remote files and the like.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the details of the source image, you may be getting errors such as 403, 404 or really anything from the remote file.

If it is a file on your own server, use local paths to get to it. Otherwise you're making the server have to connect to itself and retrieve something it already has, which is about as daft as people in jQuery doing `$("#"+$(this).attr("id"))` (please, *please* don't do this XD)

If it is indeed a remote file, you're still overcomplicating. Just use:

```
copy("http://example.com/some/remote/file.jpg","localcopy.jpg");
```

This will be much faster and you will get an exact copy of the file, not a recompressed version (which for JPEG will be lower quality every time).

Comment: I did try this, but again nothing was getting saved to the new directory. Is there anything special i need enabled on the server to do a copy?

Comment: Enable error reporting. If nothing's happening, then something's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, i get the following: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Comment: That doesn't sound like an error you should be able to get, unless you're putting a remote URL in the destination...